# unable to populate the selected response from ajax in a select dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a json response as below :

```
{
  "respData": [
    {
      "salesTargetId": "c51a411e-44ed-496c-85c0-52d76bd97c64",
      "userId": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "type": "SALES",
      "month": "April",
      "year": "2021",
      "target": 1550,
      "actual": 500,
      "createdBy": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "createdDate": "2021-05-06 15:51:41",
      "brand": "Cipla",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "salesTargetId": "d2053e0a-c0b4-4adf-bf98-05789cb8f72f",
      "userId": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "type": "SALES",
      "month": "April",
      "year": "2021",
      "target": 3000,
      "actual": 1000,
      "createdBy": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "createdDate": "2021-05-06 16:07:41",
      "brand": "Glaxo",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to populate this data in a table, as per the below code, but am unable to add "selected=selected" for the month dropdown, please help

```
$.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "updateDistributionData",
                  data: {
                    userId: userid
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  //if received a response from the server <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
                  success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data.respData, function(key, value) {
                        var salesTargetId = value.salesTargetId.trim();
                        var actionSelect = '<select id="Action"> <option value="Update">Update</option> <option value="Delete">Delete</option> </select>';
                        var month ='<select id="updateMonth">'+
                        '<option value="Jan">January</option><option value="Feb">February</option><option value="Mar">March</option><option value="Apr">April</option>' +
                        '<option value="May">May</option><option value="Jun">June</option><option value="Jul">July</option><option value="Aug">August</option>'+
                        '<option value="Sep">September</option><option value="Oct">October</option><option value="Nov">November</option><option value="Dec">December</option></select>';
                        
                        
                        
                        
                      var html = '<tr>' +
                        '<td><input type="hidden" name=delete-item id="'+salesTargetId+'" value="'+salesTargetId+'"/>'+actionSelect+'</td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.year + '"/></td>' +
                        '<td>'+month'</td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.brand + '"/></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.target + '"/></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.actual + '"/></td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                      $('#update-distribution tr').first().after(html);
                    });
                  }
                });
```

Comment: What do you mean with selected=selected? there is no selected in the data

Comment: My json response is giving me the month, while display I want to make sure that value is selected in the dropdown for month

Comment: What's the json `data.respData` value that indicates the month?     Something like `'<option value="Jan"' + (value.month=='jan' ? ' selected="selected"' : "") + '/>'` ?

Comment: Or you could add the months in a loop from an array and compare that way = much less code

Comment: Note you can't repeat element ids in a page. Change to common class names instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying let's say select the April month from the dropdown

you can run this

```
    let m = 'April';
  let shorter = m.substr(0, 3);
  console.log(shorter);
  
  $('#selector').val(shorter);
```

You also could do if/else inside the dropdown but it will be much longer way.

**In your case**

```
$.each(data.respData, function(key, value) {
    var salesTargetId = value.salesTargetId.trim();
    var actionSelect = '<select id="Action"> <option value="Update">Update</option> <option value="Delete">Delete</option> </select>';
    var month ='<select class="updateMonth" data-key="' + key + '">'+
    '<option value="Jan">January</option><option value="Feb">February</option><option value="Mar">March</option><option value="Apr">April</option>' +
    '<option value="May">May</option><option value="Jun">June</option><option value="Jul">July</option><option value="Aug">August</option>'+
    '<option value="Sep">September</option><option value="Oct">October</option><option value="Nov">November</option><option value="Dec">December</option></select>';




    var html = '<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="hidden" name=delete-item id="'+salesTargetId+'" value="'+salesTargetId+'"/>'+actionSelect+'</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.year + '"/></td>' +
    '<td>'+month+'</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.brand + '"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.target + '"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.actual + '"/></td>' +
    '</tr>';

    $('#update-distribution tr').first().after(html);
    
    $('.updateMonth[data-key="' + key + '"]').val(value.month.substr(0,3))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist you must never use the same id twice. In your loop you are creating multiple selects with the same id. Thats prevents you from accessing them later on.

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "updateDistributionData",
              data: {
                userId: userid
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              //if received a response from the server <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
              success: function(data) {
                let id = 0; <--- create unique id
                $.each(data.respData, function(key, value) {
                    var salesTargetId = value.salesTargetId.trim();
                    var actionSelect = '<select id="Action_'+id+'"> <option value="Update">Update</option> <option value="Delete">Delete</option> </select>';
                    var month ='<select id="updateMonth_'+id+'">'+
                    '<option value="Jan">January</option><option value="Feb">February</option><option value="Mar">March</option><option value="Apr">April</option>' +
                    '<option value="May">May</option><option value="Jun">June</option><option value="Jul">July</option><option value="Aug">August</option>'+
                    '<option value="Sep">September</option><option value="Oct">October</option><option value="Nov">November</option><option value="Dec">December</option></select>';
                    
                    
                    
                    
                  var html = '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name=delete-item id="'+salesTargetId+'" value="'+salesTargetId+'"/>'+actionSelect+'</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.year + '"/></td>' +
                    '<td>'+month'</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.brand + '"/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.target + '"/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" value="' + value.actual + '"/></td>' +
                    '</tr>';

                  $('#update-distribution tr').first().after(html);
                  $('#updateMonth_'+id).val(value.month.substr(0,3)); <---Now you can access it here
                  id++;
                });
              }
            });
```

Comment: "First" (assuming typo)...  but what about OPs *actual* question?   This is a comment advice or part of an answer